# ListView inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm trying to put a `ListView` inside a `ListView` (a listseption hehehe). I'm able to do that and I can easily show information on the outer, and inner views. The problem is that the inner list despite showing the things i want, it can't be scrolled. Does anyone knows how to fix this?

ps.: Using an `ExpandableListView` is not an option. I really need a `ListView` within a `ListView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a ListView inside a ListView (or in general any scrolling View inside a scrolling View with the same orientation scrolling i.e. ListView inside a ScrollView). The scrolling of the inner view is disabled.

You should really reconsider your layout for the job you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! In case you need any help, go for it.

Comment: Hey, i just realized that the outer list don't need to scroll, is there a way to make just the inner list scrollable?

Comment: If you don't want your ListView scrollable, you should use another ViewGroup (i.e. a LinearLayout or a TableLayout).

Comment: The problem is that the number of itens on the list may vary.

Comment: Yeap, but you can add these items to the LinearLayout (for example) with a for loop. In case these items change, you can also remove all the existing views from the layout and add the new ones.